# Own implementation of StringTokenizer returns unexcepted (endless) output

Tags: php, string, substring, stringtokenizer

I am implementing my own StringTokenizer class in php, because the strtok function can only handle one opened tokenizer at the same time.

With

```
Hello;this;is;a;text
```

it works perfectly.
The output is:

```
**Hello**
**this**
**is**
**a**
**text**
```

But with

```
Hello;this;is;a;text;
```

it outputs:

```
**Hello**
**this**
**is**
**a**
**text**
****
****
<endless loop>
```

But I except the following output:

```
**Hello**
**this**
**is**
**a**
**text**
****
```

See my code below and please correct me:

```
class StringTokenizer
{
    private $_str;
    private $_chToken;
    private $_iPosToken = 0;
    private $_bInit;

    public function __construct($str, $chToken)
    {
        if (empty($str) && empty($chToken))
        {
            throw new Exception('String and the token char variables cannot be empty.');
        }
        elseif(empty($chToken) && !empty($str))
        {
            throw new Exception('Missing parameter: Token char cannot be empty.');
        }
        elseif(!empty($chToken) && empty($str))
        {
            throw new Exception('Missing parameter: String cannot be empty.');
        }
        elseif(!empty($chToken) && !empty($str) && is_string($str) && strlen($chToken) >= 0)
        {
            $this->_str = $str;
            $this->_chToken = $chToken;
            $this->_bInit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('TypeError: Illegal call to __construct from class StringTokenizer.');
        }
    }

    public function next()
    {
        if ($this->_iPosToken === false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->_bInit === true && (strlen($this->_str) - 1) > $this->_iPosToken)
        {
            $iCh1stPos = strpos($this->_str, $this->_chToken, $this->_iPosToken) + 1;
            $this->_iPosToken = $iCh1stPos;
            $this->_bInit = false;
            return substr($this->_str, 0, $this->_iPosToken - 1);
        }
        elseif ($this->_bInit === false && (strlen($this->_str) - 1) > $this->_iPosToken)
        {
            $iCh1stPos = $this->_iPosToken;
            $iCh2ndPos = strpos($this->_str, $this->_chToken, $this->_iPosToken);
            if ($iCh2ndPos === false)
            {
                $this->_iPosToken = false;
                return substr($this->_str, $iCh1stPos);
            }
            else 
            {
                $this->_iPosToken = $iCh2ndPos + 1;
                return substr($this->_str, $iCh1stPos, $iCh2ndPos - $iCh1stPos);
            }
        }
    }

    public function hasNext()
    {
        return strpos($this->_str, $this->chToken, $this->_iPosToken) === false ? false : true;
    }
}
$strText = 'Hello;this;is;a;text';
$tokenizer = new StringTokenizer($strText, ';');
$tok = $tokenizer->Next();
while ($tok !== false)
{
    echo '**' . $tok . '**' . PHP_EOL;
    $tok = $tokenizer->next();
}
exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the third condition in the next() is this. String length is 26 and the last character match is 26 which you represent with the _iPosToken. so the condition in the 3rd if is false and the block never executes for the last semicolon.

> A function in php returns NULL not FALSE by default.[source](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

and the while never terminates at the bottom of  the code.

So you have two options here. change the condition in the 3rd if to (strlen($this->_str)) >= $this->_iPosToken
OR
add a 4th condtion which returns false, as shown below.

```
public function next()
{
    if ($this->_iPosToken === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->_bInit === true && (strlen($this->_str) - 1) > $this->_iPosToken)
    {
        $iCh1stPos = strpos($this->_str, $this->_chToken, $this->_iPosToken) + 1;
        $this->_iPosToken = $iCh1stPos;
        $this->_bInit = false;
        return substr($this->_str, 0, $this->_iPosToken - 1);
    }
    elseif ($this->_bInit === false && (strlen($this->_str)-1 ) > $this->_iPosToken)
    {
        $iCh1stPos = $this->_iPosToken;

        echo $this->_iPosToken;
        $iCh2ndPos = strpos($this->_str, $this->_chToken, $this->_iPosToken);
        if ($iCh2ndPos === FALSE) // You can chuck this if block. I put a echo here and                             //it never executed.
         {

                            $this->_iPosToken = false;


            return substr($this->_str, $iCh1stPos);
        }
        else
        {

            $this->_iPosToken = $iCh2ndPos + 1;
            return substr($this->_str, $iCh1stPos, $iCh2ndPos - $iCh1stPos);
        }
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exact answer to my question. The other one solved it, too, but it wasn´t the exact answer.
Edit: I tested it, works fine. But the last one doesn´t return ****. Doesn´t really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you like reinvent the wheel ?

You can use `explode` function, and then implements `Iterator` pattern in this tokenizer, i think it's an good approach.

http://php.net/explode 
https://www.php.net/Iterator

### Example

```
<?php

class StringTokenizer implements Iterator
{
  private $tokens = [];

  private $position = 0;

  public function __construct($string, $separator) 
  {
    $this->tokens = explode($separator, $string);
  }

  public function rewind()
  {
    $this->position = 0;
  }

  public function current()
  {
    return $this->tokens[$this->position];
  }

  public function next()
  {
    ++ $this->position;
  }

  public function key()
  {
    return $this->position;
  }

  public function valid()
  {
    return isset($this->tokens[$this->position]);
  }
}
```

And using it:

```
$tokenizer = new StringTokenizer('h;e;l;l;o;', ';');

while($tokenizer->valid()) {
  printf('**%s**', $tokenizer->current());

  $tokenizer->next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I am using now next() as combination of valid current to keep it more in Java style. So, next() returns the next string in the set of strings.